# Stack two y axes using chart.js

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a mixed chart featuring both a line and a bar chart. Instead of having two y axes where one y axis is shown on the left of the chart and the other y axis is shown on the right of the chart, is it possible to show both the two y-axes on say the left but have one above and the other below? It's sort of like having two charts - one above and one below - except they share the same x axis.

Here's my code so far.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Bar Dataset',
      yAxisID: 'A',
      data: [10, 20, 30, 40]
    }, {
      label: 'Line Dataset',
      yAxisID: 'B',
      data: [100, 90, 70, 75],
      type: 'line',
      fill: "start"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
          id: "A",
          position: 'right',
          gridLines: {
            display: true
          },
          ticks: {
            display: true,
            fontFamily: myfont,
            fontSize: myfontsize,
            min: 0,
            max: 100
          }
        },
        {
          id: "B",
          position: 'left',
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
          },
          ticks: {
            reverse: true,
            display: true,
            fontFamily: myfont,
            fontSize: myfontsize,
            min: 0,
            max: 100
          }
        }
      ],
      xAxes: [{
        id: "x-axis-0",
        gridLines: {
          display: false
        },
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Sharing some code would be useful! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use two canvas, one for each chart.

You can hide the xAxis for the upper chart with `options2.scales.xAxes[0].display = true`.

And you must take care of the offset. Either both need offset or none because bar chart has offset and line chart not.
`options2.scales.xAxes[0].offset = false` or the other way around, `offset = true for the other chart`.

[Full functional example in JSBin](https://jsbin.com/vesocapezi/5/edit?html,js,output)